# Patterns for Android Game Development?

Tags: android, design-patterns, opengl-es

What are the good patterns to use in developing android games?
And if it is a simple 2D side scrolling game, do you still need to use OpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an open-source 2d scroller http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/ and a video by the author about opengl vs android apis and other things. http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html

Comment: The links provided above are really comprehensive and were all I needed to get started some time ago. You might also like this earlier one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic which features the same speaker. A quick recap of some Android programming intrinsics is here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Comment: That second link gave me a 404: Not found error

Comment: Whoops sorry > http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Answer (score 1):

> And if it is a simple 2D side scrolling game, do you still need to use OpenGL?

Even if your game runs well on just the CPU you will **A.** limit your capacity for expanding on your design and **B.** use up more of the user's battery.

Answer (score 1):

This (and the link inside) may be a good place to start.
http://m3ph1st0s.blogspot.ro/2012/12/create-games-with-libgdx-library-in.html